# doesn't return exact value

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

email value is passed from one page to another through the following

```
  $.ajax({
type:'post',
    url:'email.php',
    data:{email: email},
    success:function(msg){
    alert(msg);         
    }
 });
```

$s show the email id.I echoed $echeck and $echk for testing. $echk doesn't return 1.

```
  $s=$_POST['email'];
  echo $echeck="select email from register where email=".$_POST['email'];
  echo $echk=mysql_query($echeck);
  echo $ecount=mysql_num_rows($echk);
```

Comment: Its not clear what your question is.

Comment: So what does #echk give?

Comment: $echk return 1 if the query get execute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote your string value in sql queries.

```
echo $echeck="select email from register where email='".$_POST['email']."'";
```

Answer (score 1):

You are providing a string without quotes in your query.

Try:

```
echo $echeck="select email from register where email='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email'])."'";
```

The `mysql_real_escape_string` is there to avoid nastiness when `$_POST['email']` contains quotes, or worse.